# RegEx not behaving as expected, but works when x modifier

Tags: regex

I have this RegEx:

```
(?<=\s)(?i)bananas?(\*(x|u|z))?(?=<VNW)
```

Which should find hits such as:

```
banana*x
bananas
Bananas*z
```

only when preceded by a space (white space character is fine I guess? Is there a shorthand for only a space?) and followed by `<VNW`.

However, when testing with [an online regex tester](https://regex101.com/), this does not behave as expected. Try for instance `bananas*z<VNW`. It won't be a match. However, when adding the x modifier, it seems to work fine! Change the RegEx to:

```
(?<=\s)(?ix)bananas?(\*(x|u|z))?(?=<VNW)
```

And it ought to work fine. But I don't get why? There's not a single space in my query, nor is there in the regex. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is fine expect that you have an **extra space at the end**.

Remove that and it will work fine

```
(?<=\s)(?i)bananas?(\*(x|u|z))?(?=<VNW)
```

[**Regex example link**](https://regex101.com/r/uK6qL6/2)